# How to discourage excessive negative voting?

Tags: discussion

Negative voting seems to have a disproportional negative effects on new users. Many will not return after being welcomed by a negative vote. One or two questions get a negative vote and a new prespective user is lost. In addition, some of the more established user seems to be eager to give a negative vote at a first chance the get. The fact is that the nature of the site deals heavily with anonymity, and this in itself reduce the number of the people who are willing to be exposed. In addition the excessive negative votings humiliate a lot of decent folks who come to the site for the first time. This does not seem to be a helpful way to expand the user base. Comments and in exeptional cases flags can do the job to guide the new user in understanding how to use the site. What is your point of view about this matter?